# PHP merge 2 array with same key

Tags: php, arrays

Hi everyone how I can merge/push one array to another to specific keys? Here is my arrays:

```
// Array 1
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => test
        )
)

// Array 2
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [age] => 25
        )
)
```

I want this result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => test
            [age] => 25
        )
)
```

I use PHP and will be very grateful if someone help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php ?

Comment: @MarcB I try but didnt get success? Any idea how to make it? Thanks.

Comment: Post the code you used when trying array merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = [ 1 => [ "name" => "Test" ] ];
$arr2 = [ 1 => [ "age" => 25 ] ];

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
     if (isset($arr2[$key])) {
        $arr[$key] = array_merge($value,$arr2[$key]);
     }
}

print_r($arr);
```

Check the output at https://eval.in/602680

Comment: I found a bug, if i have more than one array (array 1) the age set only on last. How to fix that? Thanks.

Comment: Probably add another `if` after the `isset($arr2[$key])` saying `if (isset($arr3[$key])) { $arr[$key] = array_merge($arr[$key],$arr3[$key])` and so on, though I suspect you could do this a lot more effectively if you had multiple entries in the same array.

Answer (score 0):

Just add them together:

```
<?php
$array1 = array('name' => 'test');
$array2 = array('age' => 21);

var_dump($array1 + $array2);
```